# jQuery autocomplete not showing while typing with Rest API

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an `autocomplete` in my form. The idea is to pull data from an API when you type a keyword in a textbox. Please see code that I currently have.

```
$('#song').on('keyup', function () {
    const query = $(this).val();
        var songData = {};
        GetSongs(query, function (songs) {
            $.each(songs, function (index, song) {
                songData[song.name] = null;
            });
        });

        $('#song').autocomplete({
            data: songData
        });
});

function GetSongs(query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/songs?query=' + query
    }).then(function (response) {
        callback(response.data);
    });
}
```

The code above partially working. The problem that I encountered is that after typing a keyword, the `autocomplete` is not showing. It will only show when you leave the textbox and re focus on the textbox again. I'm totally not sure what's happening here. Hope someone can guide me on this.

Btw, I only use `jquery-3.4.1.js` and **NOT** using the `jquery-ui` as this is already an existing code that I'm enhancing.

TIA

Comment: The `data` variable in your code seems undefined.

Comment: I just updated the code. I type a wrong variable.

Comment: `songData` is filled asynchronously, in `GetSongs`, but you use its value synchronously, before it has been filled.

Comment: you should probably move `autocomplete` method inside `GetSongs`, and include that code, and provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). also, not related to `nodejs` and `jquery-ui-autocomplete`

Comment: @traynor actually I also did that. But still when I type the auto suggestion is not showing unless you lost focus in the textbox and re focus again

Comment: well, then the problem is with `autocomplete` implementation.. but like I said, without the code and a reproducible example it's impossible to know..